# How to analyze aggresive Google ad clicks using Apache logs

Tags: google-adsense, logs

Last week I received email from Google that they are blocking my AdSense account because they traced extensive ad clicks and asked to provide the server logs for further assessment. I have sent them the apache logs and they revert back to me saying they cant unblock because their expert team confirmed the invalid clicks between 15-17th of September without giving anymore information.

Now I am really new to the analyzing the server logs and I have no idea what to analyze from those logs which are 1.5GB in file size. Please guide me what should I look for in those logs to find what made my account block my AdSense account.

Comment: You got me! I would ask them to explain it to you so that you understand. Simply put, Google AdSense clicks do not show up in *your* log files. Unless I missed something new. As well, the invalid clicks would have to be generated by you, I would imagine. Are they suggesting this? If not, perhaps they can tell you more so that you can block the accesses and get reinstated. If so, I would ask for more explanation as to how they determined you were doing such a thing. In the end, I do not think they really have to explain anything. But it sure would help.

Comment: Look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_fraud Competitors of publishers: and Other malicious intent:. If Google provided a time-line and any other clue, you may simply have to scroll through the log file to the date and time and look for excessive accesses from specific domain names and IP addresses. You still may not have the culprit, but you may be able to identify something of questionable motive. I also recommend using http://piwik.org/ to analyze your log files. It seems to be one of the best and it is FREE! (I should own stock!)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have all the information to analyze this yourself.  You would also need the ad click logs from Google.

They likely had some clicks on ads in their logs associated with a user and IP address.   They were suspicious.   It didn't look like the clicks from a user that was actually browsing your site.   They asked for your server logs so they could search for this IP address and see what that user was doing on your site.

When they got the logs, they pulled out the records associated with that IP address and viewed the activity.   What they actually discovered was one of the following scenarios:

- The IP address that was clicking on ads wasn't in the server logs.  This would indicate that it was a bot that was requesting the ads from them and simulating clicks without actually visiting the site.
- They found a user that was visiting many pages on your site and clicking on the ads on every single page.  This would indicate that somebody was just trying to drive up your revenue without being interested in the ads themselves
- They found an IP addres clicking on ads that was also using the `/admin` section of your website.  That would indicate that somebody associated with your website was clicking on ads in violation of the AdSense terms of service.